# Creating, recreating many Emacs-windows

Tags: emacs

From time to time I would like to create a bunch of say 8 windows with some fixed names, with some shells, all split vertically. So I do a lot of C-x 2 and rearrange the window size.  Isn't there a better way to do this?

So the desktop saver is no help to me, unless I missed something.

(By windows, I mean emacs-windows, not the windows "window-managers" are built-for which you can Alt-Tab to)

Comment: Have you tried 'winner-mode' ?

Comment: Also, check this out: I just discovered it, and it made my life much better: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NumberedWindows
Also, unless I am much mistaken, your Emacs "desktop" is actually the list of buffers that you have been editing, so it will be no help with layouts.  I know, one of those weird, counter-intuitive Emacs terms, but you can't get mad because they were probably using them first.

Comment: I've upvoted the question.   This is a pretty common place to get to when using emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your current window layout  to the [Configurations register](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Configuration-Registers.html#Configuration-Registers)

However, to make it persistent across sessions, you might need a tool like [Policy Switch.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PolicySwitch)

[Emacs Screen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen) also looks very promising for what you want.

This is something that I have been meaning to do for myself for a long time; appreciate the nudge ;)

Answer (score 1):

While there are various prepackaged solutions for recording and saving windows and frame congurations as alluded to in the other answer, it is quite easy to do this directly.

You can call 'make-frame' directly with the frame parameters you want. An example may look like this:

```
(make-frame '((name . "(SHELL)") 
              (icon-name . "(SHELL)") 
              (icon-type) 
              (top . 720) 
              (left . 1300) 
              (height . 30) 
              (width . 81)))
```

This call will not only create the frame (in case you are running under a windowing system) but also return the newly created frame.

If you want a quick peek at what parameters are available, you can make a call like this:

```
(frame-parameters)
```

which will return the parameters of the currently selected frame.

You can change one or more parameters of a frame with 'modify-frame-parameters' and get a list of all frames with 'frames-on-display-list'.

There are many more nifty functions that allows you to deal with frames. Check the documentation for more info.